# Дублирование последнего числа в ListBox

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

Мне нужно считать все числа из файла в бинарном режиме (мне принципиально важно именно в этом режиме считывать числа) и добавить в ListBox. По непонятной причине у меня дублируется число.

В данном случае я записал цифру 1 РОВНО ОДИН РАЗ и она добавилась 2 раза в ListBox.

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        int n = 0;
        String^g = "";
        ifstream d;
        d.open("12.dat", ios::binary);
         do {
            d.read((char*)&n, sizeof(int));
            g = System::Convert::ToString(n);
            listBox1->Items->Add(n);
         } while (!d.eof());
        d.close();


    }
```

Comment: что это за синтаксис такой: `System::Object^  sender`?

Comment: это стандартная конструкция при каждом создании обработчика события.В данном случае это относится к обработчику события button3_Click.По крайней мере это не является причиной проблемы.

Comment: `eof` устанавливается после попытки чтения за пределами файла, так что у вас неверное условие - используйте `do while`

Comment: Вы используете WinForms. Это GUI-библиотека платформы .NET. Код под неё пишется на языке C++/CLI. Поэтому будет лучше весь код написать на этом языке. То есть выкиньте `ifstream`. Возьмите взамен средства [System.IO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, это сработает если я запишу в файл только одно число

Comment: @kitov.256stack почему это?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,потому что я проверил только что

Comment: @kitov.256stack не знаю что вы там проверяли - я не телепат, выложите код

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch,  добавил

Comment: @kitov.256stack ну а кто будет проверять правильно ли отработала `read`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch,и какую именно вы проверку предлагаете ?

Comment: @kitov.256stack вы так ничего и не поняли: `read` устанавливает `eof` только после попытки чтения (и я об этом уже писал!) так что когда вы читаете, то вы должны проверить - а получили ли вы значение вообще? Сдесь немного и моя вина - возможно я ввел вас в заблуждение предложением использовать `do while` - сдесь можно обойтись вообще без условия: `while(true) { if (read(.., ..)) { ... } else break; }` в таком случае у вас при первой же проблеме со считыванием произойдет выход из цикла. А уж за пределами можно без труда проверить почему это произошло.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch,благодарю вы решили мою проблему оформите последнее сообщение как ответ я поставлю вам галочку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что read устанавливает `eof` только после попытки чтения, так что когда вы читаете, то вы должны проверить - а получили ли вы значение вообще? Cдесь можно обойтись вообще без условия, достаточно:

```
while(true) {
  if (read(.., ..))
    { ... }
  else
    break;
}
```

В таком случае у вас при первой же проблеме со считыванием произойдет выход из цикла. А уж за пределами можно без труда проверить почему это произошло.